# delivering multilingual content in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, multilingual

I'm working on a project to deliver a  multilingual content in SharePoint 2010.

What will the best approach without doing a lot of customization  etc...

Can this be achieved out of the box.

Tips and resources would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be achieved out of box, in our current deployment which is in SharePoint 2007 we use different master pages and then different web applications for different languages, which means different resources for each language in our custom code solutions. There might be a better solution which I am not aware of for SP 2007 at the moment.

However in SharePoint 2010 there's few OTB solutions that can consumed while creating public sites in different languages and one of them is MUI.

[Plan for multilingual sites (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc262055%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

There is another feature in SP 2010 named as **Variations**.

> SharePoint Variations allows copying sites and content from the source
>   variation label to one or more target variation labels. By default,
>   the variations feature copies only the site structure and publishing
>   pages from the Pages library of the source variation label.

For more information check this links out,

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/14/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics.aspx

Comment: Raja thanks for the reply.With the SP 2007 solution how did you manage to sync content if you had different web apps?

Comment: @naijacoder we got different web applications and they are not synchronizing anything or any content. Yes, it is duplication of data but in few cases to get best results you have to do it.